# Java - CONTINUATION FROM:35581167 - EOF Exception when trying to recieve ImageIcons through ObjectInputStream.readObject()

Tags: java, object, server, client, imageicon

This is a continuation from the previous question: 35581167

Tested that the previous information is still sent through via `writeObject(<string>)` which it is, but when the program reaches the `readObject()` for the first ImageIcon, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at AuctionClient.retrieveItemInformation(AuctionClient.java:378)
at AuctionClient.main(AuctionClient.java:356)
```

This is the changed code for each section:

Server thread code Updated:

```
public ClientHandler(Socket socket, BiddingItem item1, BiddingItem item2, int number) throws IOException
{
    client = socket;
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    startedItem1 = item1;
    startedItem2 = item2;
    clientNumber = number;
}
```

Sending information to client:

```
public void run()
{
    //previous code..
    try
    {
        output.writeObject(clientNumber);

        output.writeObject(Integer.toString(startedItem1.getCode()));
        output.writeObject(startedItem1.getDescription());
        output.writeObject(startedItem1.getDeadlineString());
        output.writeObject(startedItem1.getCurrentPrice());

        output.writeObject(Integer.toString(startedItem2.getCode()));
        output.writeObject(startedItem2.getDescription());
        output.writeObject(startedItem2.getDeadlineString());
        output.writeObject(startedItem2.getCurrentPrice());

        output.writeObject(startedItem1.getImage());
        output.writeObject(startedItem2.getImage());
    }
    catch(IOException IOEx)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to send information!");
    }
    //code continues...
}
```

Client creating input stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException 
{
    //previous code...
    try
    {
        txtBoxServerMessage.setText("CLIENT: Attempting to connect to server...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        socket = new Socket(host, PORT);

        inputFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        outputToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx)
    {
        txtBoxServerMessage.setText("CLIENT-ERROR: Unable to connect to server! Exiting...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.exit(1);
    }
//code continues...
}
```

Function that client uses to accept information:

```
private static void retrieveItemInformation() throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{
    txtBoxServerMessage.setText("CLIENT: Waiting for Item Information...");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    clientNumber = (int) inputFromServer.readObject();

    item1Code = (String) inputFromServer.readObject();
    item1Desc = (String) inputFromServer.readObject();
    item1Deadline = (String) inputFromServer.readObject();
    item1AuctionValue = (double) inputFromServer.readObject();

    item2Code = (String) inputFromServer.readObject();
    item2Desc = (String) inputFromServer.readObject();
    item2Deadline = (String) inputFromServer.readObject();
    item2AuctionValue = (double) inputFromServer.readObject();

    item1Image = (ImageIcon) inputFromServer.readObject(); // READING IMAGE 1 = LINE 378
    item2Image = (ImageIcon) inputFromServer.readObject(); // READING IMAGE 2

    txtBoxServerMessage.setText("DEBUG: FINISHED IMAGE");
    txtBoxServerMessage.setText("CLIENT: Information Recieved! Displaying...");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    comboItemSelect.addItem(item1Code);
    comboItemSelect.addItem(item2Code);
    txtBoxClientNumber.setText(String.valueOf(clientNumber));

    updateDisplay();

}
```

Comment: The stack trace shows that the error occurred on line 378 of AuctionClient.java.  Which line of code is that?

Comment: Sorry I should of included that, line 378 is the line with comment //READING IMAGE 1

Comment: Are you sure your client isn't throwing an exception?  Replace your System.out.println with `IOEx.printStackTrace();` or `throw new RuntimeException("Unable to send information: " + IOEx, IOEx);`.

Comment: Changed it to IOEx.printStackTrace(), now the server is throwing an error saying its failed to load image contents, no doubt it got to EOF because the server couldn't load the image to actually send it via the Output stream, I will have a play about with the image creation and see what I can find, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sorted it! I wasn't initialising the ImageIcons properly, problem solved thanks again @VGR